# Adding a value to a range of values in an array in Python without using a for loop

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to learn Python and I have run into a problem.

I am attempting to complete the [Array Manipulation](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem) challenge on hackerrank.

A part of solving it requires me to add a number to a range of values in an array multiple times.

So far I have been able to come up with this:

```
def arrayManipulation(n, queries):
 x = [0]*n
 for i in range(len(queries)): 
    for i2 in range(queries[i][0], queries[i][1]+1):
        x[i2-1]+= queries[i][2]         
 return max(x)
```

But I'm not able to solve 7 of the test cases due to timeout, and I'm guessing I am missing something that would allow me to solve this without the 2nd for loop. Any ideas?

Comment: "I'm trying to learn Python and I have run into a problem." - This is a HARD problem on HackerRank. Have you already worked through enough Easy/Medium problems to feel confident in those skills?

Comment: Yeah, i have done almost every problem on arrays(the only ones i haven't done is this one and Dynamic Arrays) and some of the linked list/binary tree problems and i have decided to go back and finish the unsolved array ones.

Answer (score 0):

For a very large `n`, building an actual list/array of `n` is likely to be inefficient and unnecessary.  Consider the input:

```
n = 1000
queries = [
    [100, 500, 3],
    [400, 800, 7],
    [600, 900, 1],
]
```

You don't have 1000 unique values, you really just have 7 chunks:

```
range(0, 100)
range(100, 400)
range(400, 500)
range(500, 600)
range(600, 800)
range(800, 900)
range(900, 1000)
```

Each `query` will map to some subset of these chunks; no query will apply to only part of a chunk.  Consequently, you can compute the effect of each `query` in its entirety without ever having to iterate over the full range of `n`, or having to iterate over `range(a, b+1)` *at all*.

Actually implementing this as a solution is left as an exercise to the reader, but this is the algorithmic route I'd pursue if you're timing out on very large `n` values.  (Note that this is not an easy coding problem, and is probably not suitable if you're just starting out!)

Answer (score -1):

You can use map(), should be more efficient. Look here as a ref.:

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/map.html